# Image of a continuous mapping and measureability issues

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous mapping.

Then, if I understand correctly:

- The image of $f$ needn't be Lebesgue measurable.
- The pushforward of the Lebesgue measure across $f$, being a Borel measure, has well-defined support, and this support is a closed set.
- Hence the image of $f$ needn't agree with the support of the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure.

> **Questions.**
>
> **Q0.** Is this correct? If so, an instructive example or two would be appreciated.
>
> **Q1.** Would it be fair to the say that the support of the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure across $f$ is always the closure of the image of $f$? If not, what is the correct statement of the relationship between the image of $f$ and the support of the pushforward of the Lebesgue measure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Q0: no, not correct.  The image of $f$ can be written
$$f(\mathbb{R}) = \bigcup_n f([-n,n])$$
which is a countable union of compact (hence closed) sets.  So it is Borel (even $F_\sigma$) and Lebesgue measurable.

This still happens if you replace $\mathbb{R}$ by another Polish space; the continuous image of a Polish space into another Polish space is (by definition) analytic, and all analytic sets in a Polish space are universally measurable (though not necessarily Borel).  The same happens if you only require $f$ to be Borel measurable.

But it is true that the image of $f$ need not equal the support of the pushforward, since the support must be closed and the image need not be.  Example: $f(x) = \arctan x$.

Q1: let $\mu$ be the pushforward of $m$ under $f$ and let $E$ be the support of $\mu$.  The inclusion $E \subset \overline{f(\mathbb{R})}$ is an immediate consequence of definitions.  Conversely, let $U = E^c$.  Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is an open set of Lebesgue measure zero, so it must be empty.  That means $f(\mathbb{R}) \subset E$.  Since $E$ is closed we also have $\overline{f(\mathbb{R})}\subset E$.

Comment: Thanks for your help!